# Can $p ∧ q$, where $p$ and $q$ are propositional variables, be a proposition?

Tags: logic

**Edit:**
I have removed the original text in favor of showing the specific passages in the book that I am stuck on. Sorry about the inconvenience.

I am wondering whether $p ∧ q$ can be a proposition when $p$ and $q$ are both propositional variables. It seems to me that my book in one case says that a proposition can't have a variable truth value and then states that $p ∧ q$ is a proposition, even though it surely also has a variable truth value.

Page 2:

> Consider the following sentences.
>
> 1. What time is it?
> 2. Read this carefully.
> 3. $x + 1 = 2$
> 4. $x + y = z$
>
> Sentences 1 and 2 are not propositions because they are not declarative sentences. Sentences 3 and 4 are not propositions because they are neither true nor false. Note that each of sentences 3 and 4 can be turned into a proposition if we assign values to the variables.

Page 26:

> Note that we will use the term "compound proposition" to refer to an expression formed from propositional variables using logical operators, such as $p ∧ q$.

Rosen, K. H. (2019). *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications Eighth Edition*. New York, NY: McGraw-Hill Education.

Couldn't we have stated the following?

"$p ∧ q$ is not a proposition because it is neither true nor false. Note that it could be turned into a proposition if we assign values to the variables $p$ and $q$."

Comment: Surely that would come under the “fair use” exception?

Comment: Here, you are using it for **scholarly analysis**, and the copyright infringement contains this as an exception. or else you can quote the page number and the name of the book.

Comment: $x=5$ here should be interpreted as "$x$ is defined to be 5". The way you're thinking about that is not wrong per se, but it is not the intended interpretation in this case. Some authors use $:=$ to denote a definition or even $\equiv$ to distinguish definition from equality.

Comment: @CameronWilliams The statement $x = 5$ is my rewriting of the original $x + 1 = 2$. There it is made clear that x is a variable. Therefore, the statement isn't meant to define x as a given constant value.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I have edited the post now. Hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: @Kumar Thanks. I have now added the specific passages from my book.

Comment: @Lubin Thanks for the tip. I have added the quotes from my mathematics book.

Answer (score 1):

$x=5$ is said to be a predicate of one variable denoted by $P(x)$.

$p \land q$ can also be seen as a predicate (of two variables) whose truth value (val) depends on truth values of $p$ and $q$.

We could denote it by
$$Q(val(p),val(q))$$
for example

$$val(Q(1,0))=0$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is a numerical constant, $x=5$ is a proposition; otherwise, it can be thought of as a number-to-boolean function. If $p,\,q$ are boolean or propositional constants, $p\land q$ is a proposition; otherwise, it is a [truth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_function).

Answer (score 0):

Some of this depends on how one's textbook defines these formulas.

According to the [*forallx*](http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf) logic textbook, "the symbol ‘=’ is a two-place predicate" in first-order logic with identity. The formula $x=5$ asserts that $x$ "is identical to" $5$. Both $x$ and $5$ "name the same thing". (page 205) It may not make sense to think of this formula as true or false.

Rather than calling $p$ and $q$ 'propositions', this textbook calls them 'atomic sentences' and 'subsentences' of the sentence $p\land q$ in truth-functional logic. (page 23) One can assign truth values to these 'sentence letters'.  One could also refer to these as propositions in truth-functional logic although this textbook doesn't use that term.

---

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Fall 2019. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to think about it is this: If you just say $p \wedge q$, with no context, then that's right, it is not a proposition, because it is just a string of symbols withouth meaning, so it is neither true or false. However, if you give the context "p is a proposition and "q is a proposition", then "$p \wedge q$" is definitely a proposition.

Similarly with $x=5.$ With no context, this is just a string of sybols with no meaning. If you give the context "$x is an irrational number", then this becomes a proposition (a false one). If you give the context "x is 5", then this is again a proposition, a true one.

Comment: "However, if you give the context "p is a proposition and "q is a proposition", then "p∧q" is definitely a proposition." I agree. What confuses me is that $p$ and $q$ are propositional variables, not propositions. I added the excerpts from the book also. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Name Hmm then in that case I would just go with what the book says. I am not a logic person. If it makes you feel any better, unless you’re studying logic, the answer to this question won’t affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

*It seems to me that you are mix-and-matching different contexts* ...

The first quote is from page 2, and the author plainly states the basic concept of **proposition** :

> A *proposition* is a declarative sentence (that is, a sentence that declares a fact) that is either true or false, but not both.

Here the context is natural language and **Examples 1&2** give natural language sentences : some are declarative sentences, stating a fact that is either true or false (e.g. Toronto is the capital of Canada) while Others are not (e.g. What time is it? : it is a question and does not state a fact).

Immediately after, the author "moves to" the preliminaries of *propostional calculus* saying :

> We use letters to denote *propositional variables* (or statement variables), that is, variables that represent propositions, just as letters are used to denote numerical variables.

This means that, when the author writes :

> Let $p$ be a proposition. The negation of $p$, denoted by $¬p$, is the statement “It is not the case that $p$.” The proposition $¬p$ is read “not $p$.”

he is stating the first rule of the syntax of the calculus, concerning the *negation* sign.

How we have to interpret it ? In this way :

> every time we replace the *statement variable* $p$ in the formula $\lnot p$ with a declarative sentence of natural Language, what we get is a new declarative sentence that is the negation of the first one.

Thus, let $p$ be replaced by the sentence "Toronto is the capital of Canada"; the corersponding formula $\lnot p$ will be : "Toronto is **not** the capital of Canada".

The same for the *conjunction* connective [page 4] :

> Let $p$ and $q$ be propositions. The conjunction of $p$ and $q$, denoted by [the formula] $p ∧ q$, is the proposition “$p$ and $q$.”

In conclusion, regarding the title question :

> Can $p ∧ q$, where $p$ and $q$ are propositional variables, be a proposition?

the answer is : $p ∧ q$ is a *formula* that will become a proposition when the propositional variables $p,q$ will be replaced by propositions.

*Note* : consider again the definition above, where the author says :

> just as letters are used to denote numerical variables.

When we write "the number $n+1$..." we are not saying that $n$ is a number, but we are saying that whatever number we assign as value to the *numerical variable* $n$ the result will be a number.

---

Regarding the fact that the *arithmetical* formula $x+1=2$ is not a declarative sentence in the language of arithmetic, you can see the post [Is logical implication always determinable from just the given statements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3342774/is-logical-implication-always-determinable-from-just-the-given-statements) for a discussion of similar examples.

Comment: I think I have come to a partial understanding by considering functions, which present an analogous situation. Say we have a function $f(x) = |x|$. Then we could talk about "the function value $f(x)$", even though it isn't a function value unless you specify $x$. Similarly, we can talk about "the proposition $p ∧ q$ " even though it isn't a proposition unless you specify $p$ and $q$. So in conclusion, it is simply a matter of phrasing or terminology. Why $x + 1 = 2$ doesn't have a truth value is something I'll have to look into. I'll check your link when I have the time.

Comment: Would you say that's fair or am I missing something?

Comment: @Name - correct; in the context of *propositional calculus* we can talk about "the proposition $p∧q$" even though it isn't a proposition unless we specify $p$ and $q$. In other words, the "rule of the game" is that whenever $p,q$ are specified, the compound formula $p \land q$ will be a proposition also.

Comment: Is there any obvious reason why this phrasing is allowed? To me, it seems imprecise.